# SQL Help - Filter by User ID

Tags: sql, relational-database

```
SELECT     projectID, urlID, COUNT(1) AS totalClicks, projectPage,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(1)
                            FROM          tblStatSessionRoutes, tblStatSessions
                            WHERE      tblStatSessionRoutes.statSessionID = tblStatSessions.ID AND tblStatSessions.projectID = tblAdClicks.projectID AND 
                                                   (tblStatSessionRoutes.leftPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage OR
                                                   tblStatSessionRoutes.rightPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage)) AS totalViews
FROM         tblAdClicks
GROUP BY projectID, urlID, projectPage
ORDER BY projectID, urlID
```

tblProjects has a field UserID, and I need this query to only show records where the project has userID = 5, so as to not show all the stats for all projects from all users

Comment: Where are you using the table tblProjects in the query above?

Comment: I'm not, but I'm having a brain fart at the end of my day and can't work out how to get it in

Comment: so what's the relationship between tblProjects.userID and other tblAdClicks?

Comment: Well that's going to be a bit tricky for us to do much with unless you can tell us how tblProjects is related to the other tables in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naively:

```
SELECT     projectID, urlID, COUNT(1) AS totalClicks, projectPage,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(1)
                            FROM          tblStatSessionRoutes, tblStatSessions
                            WHERE      tblStatSessionRoutes.statSessionID = tblStatSessions.ID AND tblStatSessions.projectID = tblAdClicks.projectID AND 
                                                   (tblStatSessionRoutes.leftPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage OR
                                                   tblStatSessionRoutes.rightPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage)) AS totalViews
FROM         tblAdClicks
WHERE projectID IN (SELECT projectID FROM tblProjects WHERE userID = 5)
GROUP BY projectID, urlID, projectPage
ORDER BY projectID, urlID
```

But it might be better with a join.  As always, check your execution plan

Comment: Cheers!  What do you mean by execution plan?

Comment: @Tom Gullen What RDBMS are you using?  In SQL Server, you can view the estimated and actual execution plan is SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know the structure of the data that you have, but if nothing else, you can always join to the following subquery:

```
select projectID from tblProjects where userID=5
```

As to what column(s) you should use for the join, I can't really tell you, since I don't know the specifics of your data.

Comment: This would return either `NULL` or `5`

Comment: Oops, I meant projectID.  Fixed!